# amplicon sequencing set up

Tags: ngs

I have .fastq files from a targeted amplicon sequencing by Illumina MiSeq run. I want to get the target sequences to perform Blast search on them. What is the pipeline to use for processing amplicon sequencing data? I also have 20% PhiX.

Comment: Usually you have the targeted regions based on the library/ panel design prior to sequencing.  Do you not have that information?  It is standard Illumina processing to remove the PhiX reads before creating the FASTQs

Comment: This is crossposted on biostars: https://www.biostars.org/p/357824/

Comment: Do you want the reads that contain the amplicon? If you know the primer sequences you could do this pretty easily